# TF 1 can't use tf.Tensor as bool condition

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am learning TF 2, but for some reason, I need to use TF 1 in a project.

However, there was a problem coming out when I used tensor as bool condition in `if`.
For simply demonstrating, I will use the following example.

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant(2.0)
if a :
  print('hi')
```

And the error:
`` using a `tf.Tensor` as a Python `bool` is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function. ``

I want the type to actually be `float`, do you have any idea?

Comment: If you want it to be a `float`, you should define it as a float instead of using a tensor. If you need to condition on tensors, you need `tf.cond`.

Comment: Thank for your reply, I use `tensor` is because I want apply some tensorflow operation on `a`.

Comment: May be you can enable eager execution after importing tensorflow as the error suggests.  `tf.enable_eager_execution()`